# Unable to play YouTube Videos

Tags: java, android, eclipse, video, android-mediaplayer

Please have a look at the following code

```
private class IntroVideoHandler implements OnClickListener
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
            try {
                mp.setDataSource("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Cb7QJwQ58T0");
                mp.prepareAsync();
                mp.start();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 


        }
```

Here, I am unable to play the youtube video either in simulator or phone. I get the following error

```
08-22 14:34:47.176: E/MediaPlayer(471): start called in state 4
08-22 14:34:47.176: E/MediaPlayer(471): error (-38, 0)
08-22 14:34:47.306: E/MediaPlayer(471): Error (-38,0)
08-22 14:34:56.426: E/MediaPlayer(471): error (1, -2147483648)
08-22 14:34:56.426: E/MediaPlayer(471): Error (1,-2147483648)
```

Why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see this [API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/)

**And**

You can not play youtube video directly in video view this way.. you have below option to play it.

1) load this url in webview

2) pass youtube video id to youtube application.

3) get RTSP url from video id and play in videoView