# How to play YouTube Video without using Intent

Tags: android, video, android-intent

I want to play YouTube videos in my application. I already tried following code: 
but this shows a complete action using YouTube but I don't want this. I would like to play videos directly. How can I achieve this?

```
context.startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CUuBdtsQx6U")));
```

Comment: you have to make a custom player for this in you app.

Comment: could you give sample code for how to make custome player in android

Comment: https://github.com/vanevery/Pro-Android-Media/tree/master/Pro%20Android%20Media%20Ch%209%20-%20Custom%20Video%20Player%20MediaPlayer%20with%20MediaController

Comment: follow this http://stackoverflow.com/a/18376035/942224

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own Activity and MediaPlayer to play the video, like :

```
MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
mp.setDataSource(FILE_PATH);
mp.prepare();
mp.start();
```

FILE_PATH is the path of file - may be url(youtube) stream or local file path.

Or else open the webview in your application:

```
WebView webview = new WebView(this); 

String htmlString = "<html> <body> <embed src=\"youtube link\"; type=application/x-shockwave-flash width="+widthOfDevice+" height="+heightOfDevice+"> </embed> </body> </html>";

webview.loadData(htmlString ,"text/html", "UTF-8");
```

Hope this helps !!!

Answer (score 0):

You've to use the Youtube Player API, and play it in VideoView.

Check out this [SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12909515/play-youtube-video-in-videoview-within-application) . It works correctly.